# android save global variable

Tags: android

i want to save a variable to be global variable on all screens i have, for example, for every connect to the localhost i am using `10.0.2.2` so i have to write that ip on every connect,and when i want to try my application on my mobile device i have to go to code and replace all the `10.0.2.2` with my system static ip `192.168.1.101` ,is there any way to say that ip on a global variable? i read that i have to used `string` on android but i don't know how, any help please

Comment: You can use Android shared preferences: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html, another solution can be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326443/passing-variables-from-one-class-to-another-wiithout-using-the-intent-get-extra/11326561#11326561

Comment: thank you , you help me , i will use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences to store and retrieve it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

//retrieve
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String ip= settings.getString("ip");
//use ip

//store
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("ip", mIp);
editor.commit();
```